# Display facebook friend list within a controller not working with outdated API usage?

Tags: php, facebook, zend-framework, facebook-graph-api

I'm new to Facebook API and I'm currently trying to get the user friend list in a variable.

This is the code, I have within my controller:

```
$accept = $this->isAcceptApp($this->app_secret);

$this->view->accept = $accept;

  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $this->app_id,
      'secret' => $this->app_secret,
      'cookie' => true,
    ));

  $session = $facebook->getSession();

    if ($session) {

          $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
```

I have this on the top of my Controller:

```
require_once("facebook.php");
```

Comment: What is not working ? Do you have any error ?

Comment: "Not working" is not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one thing I can see is a mistake right away. Quite a while ago the [SDK was altered and the login process slightly changed](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503/)...

This is what it should look like now -

```
$facebook = new Facebook($fbConfig);
$user = $facebook->getUser();  // <-- the change!!
if ($user) {
  // proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated
} else {
  // proceed knowing you require user login and/or authentication
}
```

Notice that `getSession()` is not used. Use the `getUser()` function instead.

You can get your hands on an [updated version of the SDK from github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) (currently v.3.2.2).

Comment: Don't forget about the new SSL certificate, `fb_ca_chain.crt` I believe it was, which they decided to change.

Comment: @ric - What are you referring to? Do you mean the requirement of an SSL certificate to have canvas/tab application that was [announced in may 2011](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497/)?

Comment: About 2 or 3 weeks ago our Facebook application stopped working (the communication between our website and Facebook using the PHP SDK), apparently they had changed the certificate which was giving us SSL errors, I had to disable the SSL verification, a couple hours later they released a new PHP SDK with a updated sdk. It went from 1 mb to a couple 100 mb :P